# Is there a way to cause a command line program requiring a file argument to use stdin?

Tags: java, file, command-line, portability, stdin

I'm trying to get the command pdftotext to process data from stdin, instead of having to cache intermediate data in a temporary file. Note that the pdftotext command is being executed from a Java program.

pdftotext expects a file argument and, if one isn't given, prints usage information. stdin is ignored as far as I can tell.

I do have a non-portable solution (on linux use the pseudo-file '/dev/stdin'). An ideal solution would work on linux and windows, assuming the pdftotext program was present.

Comment: forgot, as all CON devices in windows (edit DOS, not windows :D ), you need ctrl+z to close

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pdftotext seems to support the convention of using `-` as a special way of saying 'stdin'. So running
`pdftotext - mypdf.txt` will try to read the pdf document from stdin and output it to the mypdf.txt file. You can use `-` as the output file as well, in which case it'll output the converted pdf to stdout instead of a regular file.

Comment: It only supports - for the output argument, not input. For example, why I try 'pdftotext - bla.txt' I get the error 'Couldn't open file '-''.

Comment: Then you possibly have another version of the pdftotext program than I do, I'm using the one from http://poppler.freedesktop.org/ , v 0.14.5